# Subscribing to a component mouse move event

Tags: angular

I found code to subscribe to mouse move in documents, how can I subscribe to only the component instead?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = 
       fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                         .subscribe(e => {
                           console.log(e);
                         });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ElementRef

> ElementRef grants direct access to the host DOM element through its
>   nativeElement property.

```
constructor(private ele: ElementRef ){
    const host = fromEvent(this.ele.nativeElement,'click').subscribe(c=>console.log(c));
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5y6sq

Ref:https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@HostListener` to bind event with your componenet :

```
  @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event']) onMouseOver($event) {
    console.log($event)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using @HostListener (docs)

```
import {Component, NgModule, HostListener} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event']) 
  onMouseMove(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you what to keep mouse move specific to your component, then you can enclose you template in a parent div and register mousemove event specific to that

like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample-app',
  template: `<div (document:mousemove)="customMouseMoveHandler($event)"></div>`,
})
export class MyComponent {
 customMouseMoveHandler(e) {
  // add your logic here..
  console.log(e);
 }
}
```

OR you can also have a look at https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener 
with this you can subscribe to this event from your component.